# Нет проекта ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При изучении Entity столкнулся с проблемой. Нет самого проекта ADO.NET в среде visual studio.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На англоязычных сайтах эта проблема всплывала часто, но решения я не нашел(скорее всего английски на низком уровне) :(

В VS Installer все SQL библиотеки включены.

Comment: Это не проект, это item. Создавайте проект любого нужного вам типа (консольное приложение, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET и т. п.), потом делаете Add New Item - там будет ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо